# Get the previous and next values of a string in lexicographic order

Tags: javascript, database, alphabetical, lexicographic, nosql

I'm working with a noSQL database and for certain reasons I can't use equality filtering in my queries

e.g

```
select all from database where id = 10
```

is NOT allowed

but inequality filtering is allowed

e.g

```
select all from database where id > 1
```

My ID's are UNIQUE strings (emails) and I need to use equality filtering so I thought to convert inequality statements to equality statements (e.g where id = 10 could be written as Where id > 9 AND < 11).

If my ids were numbers I would use code such as this to get my key:

```
function(id)
{

    //assuming no id can be 0 and no id can be larger than 2^53-1. This will return the row with id = 10
    var result = sendToDatabaseQuery('SELECT * FROM database where id > ' + (id-1) + ' AND ' id < ' (i+1)');

}
```

With numbers it would be very easy to do this, but with Strings I have found it to be more challenging. If I have an email such as mysuperfakeemail.gmail.com how could I get the previous and next lexicographic string (I am assuming they are mysuperfakeemail.gmail.co**l** and mysuperfakeemail.gmail.co**n** respectively)? Is there an established algorithm for this type of function already? I am writing this on a nodejs server with UTF-8 characters.

Comment: When you say "NOT allowed" do you mean you get an error? Or is this some kind of assignment where you have to find a technique that avoids testing for equality?

Comment: I am using Google's Datastore and for projection queries the properties used in filters cannot be in the projections. (https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/projectionqueries#Datastore_Limitations_on_projections). I need ID property to be in the projection and I also need to use the ID to filter by.

Comment: Got it. 
This is OK
SELECT A FROM kind WHERE B = 1
and so is this
SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A > 1
but this isn't 
SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A = 1

Comment: Yes and SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A = 1 is what I need to do but am not allowed. So I am trying to rewrite it as SELECT A FROM kind WHERE A > 0 and A < 2

Comment: I hope I haven't over simplified this, but will this work?

    SELECT id FROM database WHERE id > "abc@def.com" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
    SELECT id FROM database WHERE id < "abc@def.com" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

But I don't see that Google offers the "LIMIT" key word.

Greater Than "string" works in SQL, subject to some problems with collating sequence and locale etc.

Comment: That's two separate statments.

Comment: Yes, I would like to only make one network call.